# JQuery Templates: pass html parameter into a function

Tags: jquery, html, parameters, jquery-templates

I have this JQuery template:

```
$.tmpl('<p>${text}</p>', { text: 'cool text' }).appendTo('div');
```

Works great. but now I want to pass a html parameter into it, but the following won't work.

```
$.tmpl('<p>${text}</p>', { text: '<span>cool text</span>' }).appendTo('div');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: which is the jquery template engine used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `{{html content}}` construct

```js
$.tmpl('<p>{{html text}}</p>', {
  text: '<span>cool text <b>bold</b></span>'
}).appendTo('div');
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way you can do it

```
var markup = "<span>${text}</span>";

jQuery.template( "template1", markup );
jQuery.tmpl( "template1", { text: "cool text" } ).appendTo( "div" );
```